# Is this windows 8.1 issue ? client.DownloadFile fails operation timeout

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1

Alright i was using Windows 7. My software was working extremely well and smooth.

But i wanted to move windows 8.1 as it is the newest one.

However so far i am not happy with it from programmer side.

This piece of code was working extremely well while i was in Windows 7 and using visual studio 2012.

```
client.DownloadFile(uri,path);
```

However now on windows 8.1 with visual studio 2013 Update 2 RC it miserably fails with operation timeout.

However i changed client.DownloadFile to below function and it worked very well again.

```
private static void DownloadRemoteImageFile(string uri, string fileName)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Timeout = 30000;
    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (var s = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

**So anyone have any slightest idea about this ?**

**Should i went back to Windows 7 ?**

Thank you for answers

Comment: I would say there's something in the environment causing a problem, nothing in Windows 8.1 itself would cause this to not work. Also SV2013 Update 2 RTM is already out now, but I don't think that would be a problem either. I would suggest dumping the network data to see what's going on.

Comment: Sami Kuhmonen if it was about network the other function wouldn't work. Also when i open images at browser it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have encountered this issue when using "**HttpWebRequest**" on Win 8.1 VS2013 Update 2

This is how I solve it: use **WebClient** instead it won't time out.

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient {
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri) {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        w.Timeout = 30000; // the only way to set the timeout is through overriding the base class.
        return w;
    }
}
```

and then :

```
MyWebClient c = new MyWebClient();
c.DownloadFile(url,filename);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answer do you have any idea why it happens ?

Comment: Did you tried this solution? .. I think of two possible causes to this problem: that is either the WebClient generate more headers by default, and these headers are making the server respond without time out, or their is a bug with the implementation of the HttpWebRequest.